# Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner

Tags: java, android, xml

me have a spinner list - when start in android 7 or 8 this error is show

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #164: Binary XML file line #164: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner
```

And my xml file

```
<android.widget.Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/plans_spinner"
                    style="@style/spinner_style"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_count"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="-53dp"
                    android:scrollbarSize="100dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```